# Keyboard event while inputing text

Tags: c++, linux

I don't know how to make a function which will catch keyboard events while inputting a text (stdio) (example)

```
catch_events(); // catch events will check if TAB or others keys are pressed while reading text from stdin
getline(cin, bash_command);
```

Like a linux shell when we input ec(pressed TAB) it displays all commands which starts at ec* (example: echo)

Comment: is that C or C++?

Comment: @OznOg It is C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to implement this yourself, this TAB functionality is implemented by libraries like `libreadline` or `libeditline`. Both give you a hook that tells you where the cursor is positioned when TAB is pressed.

Comment: does libreadline libary have a function to detect whenever i pressed TAB or Arrow UP key ?

Comment: It has a history function, yes.